# python pandas read_csv unnamed, first

Tags: python, pandas, csv, merge, concatenation

I'm trying to combine multiple csv files into one.
The format for csv files is the same - Column A = Index, Column B = Values

```
for f in glob.glob('C:/~/*.csv'):
df = pd.read_csv(f, header=0)
```

I made header either 0 or None.
If there is one csv file, there is no problem
But if there is multiple file, first row of csv doesn't come up
and instead there is 'Unnamed' Column or '0' and first row stuff disappear.
I tried concat, merge, append...still the same problem

can you help me fix this problem? :(

Comment: pls put sample data from csv and also show samples from df, as it's easy to debug once we can visualize the data and result. Secondly, the code you have put does not have the right indentation for python nor it combines the files.